# Alternative to Richfaces 4.5 rich:fileUpload that works in IE9

Tags: html, internet-explorer, jsf, file-upload, richfaces

I am using JSF 2.1 in a JBoss EAP 6.4 with Richfaces.
In previous versions, I used rich:fileUpload (version 3.3) and it worked great. The same component in version 4.5 is not compatible with IE9 (because the limited HTML5 support).

I'm almost done with the project and I need a replacement for this component that works with IE9 and doesn't break everything else. Can you recommend another library or fix this without breaking everything else(i.e.: primefaces, icefaces alternatives)?
I am using other richfaces components and they work fine in IE9, I just need to replace the rich:fileUpload.

My use case is simple, I need the ability to upload multiple files and show the user a grid of the uploaded files. This is component right now:

```
<rich:fileUpload id="fileUp" 
            fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadBean.fileUploadListener}"
            addLabel="Add File"         
            maxFilesQuantity="-1"
            immediateUpload="true"
            noDuplicate="true"
            render="filePanel errorPanel">
        </rich:fileUpload>
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Post what you use of the `rich:fileUpload` that is not in the jsf fileupload. Then others can provide better alternatives.

Comment: I just added my use case for better detail, thanks for your comment Kukeltje. Also, JBoss EAP 6.4 has JSF 2.1 bundled, so h:inputFile is not available. Changing the jsf version is not an alternative (but I'd like to know if inputFile works for my use case).

Comment: Uhhhmmm. but the first line of your question states "JSF-2.2"... So that is not correct?

Comment: Can you describe what does not work / does not compatible? `fileUpload` component from RichaFaces 4.3 was tested with IE 9 and was working without problem.

Comment: @VasilLukach: Check this: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/252003

Comment: I'd like to propose http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21344019/jsf-2-1-cant-import-hinputfile/33811533#33811533 as a 'duplicate'. Not the accepted answer, but the added one.

Comment: Hi @Kukeltje, I'm trying that solution, but the Multipart filter is not working (multipartRequest.getParts() method is returning an empty collection).

Comment: @Rafael If you don't need the latest version of RichaFaces, then you can try it with version 4.3 or 4.4, where `fileUpload` component was working in IE 9 without problem. As I understand, problem is in 4.5 only.

Comment: @VasilLuckach: wonder why they did not create some fallback..

Comment: Yep, that's strange... FYI, I'm now using Primefaces fileuplad inside an iframe (I tried using it in the same xhtml, but RF and PF have compatibility issues).